# In Windows is there way to drag files onto the taskbar icon instead and have the application respond

Tags: windows

In Windows is there way to drag files onto the taskbar icon instead and have the application respond, or is this whole notion of dragging files onto minimized icons purely an OSX thing and not relevent to Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly an operation you'd use in Windows as well.  It brings the window associated with the taskbar button to the foreground.  You need to use it when the target window is overlapped so is not accessible to drop on.

But no, you can't drop on the button.

You expose yourself to drag+drop notifications by calling [RegisterDragDrop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You'll get callback notifications, later, through the IDropTarget interface methods you implement:

- your DragEnter() method is called when the mouse cursor enters your window.  It lets you check whether you're happy about the kind of object that's being dragged.  The user gets feedback through (typically) the cursor shape
- your DragOver() method is called when the mouse is moved while it is inside your window.  That's useful if you want to make the drag target more selective, give dynamic feedback or need additional effects like scrolling a window
- your DragLeave() method is called when the mouse cursor leaves your window again, you use it to restore whatever you did in the other callbacks
- your Drop() method is called when the user release the mouse button to drop.

Comment: So when you drag the item onto the icon, it should show the main window of the application even if minimized, and then you have to drag and drop the item to the window itself, if you just try and drop on the icon nothing will happen, right ?

Comment: follow up question is it the same for dropping files onto the system tray ?

Comment: It is the same.  You have to have a valid HWND for the RegisterDragDrop() method, a notification icon is not a window nor is it owned by your process.  You could create [your own deskband](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to achieve something similar.  Beware the cost, first thing I do when I get one is to uninstall the program that created it.

Comment: @Has Passant sorry one more question how do you have menu items to the context menu for a taskbar button, Ive maged to add them to the applications System tray icon but not the more visible toolbar icon

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions